# Google Maps API with key not working on Domain

Tags: google-maps, google-api, domainkeys

i tried to set up a simple map: http://pan-american.ch and keep getting the same error in the JS Console:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
>   Your site URL to be authorized:

on this Domain http://map2.codedesign.ch the key works fine.

so my question is - where can i add Domains...

Answer (score 1):

You want to setup the referrers to allow `http://pan-american.ch`.
See the [Google Documentation on Setting up API keys](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en&ref_topic=6262490):

> **Setting up API keys**
>
> If your client application does not use OAuth 2.0, then it must include an API key when it calls an API that's enabled within a Google Cloud Platform project. The application passes this key into all API requests as a key=API_key parameter.
>
> To create your application's API key:
>
> 1. Go to the Cloud Platform Console.
> 2. From the projects list, select a project or create a new one.
> 3. If the API Manager page isn't already open, open the menu  Gallery Menu  and select API Manager.
> 4. On the left, choose Credentials.
> 5. Click Create credentials and then select API key.
> 6. Choose the type of key to use. (API key types are described in more detail in the following sections.) If you're unsure whether an API key is appropriate for the API you're calling, select Help me choose and follow the instructions to pick the right credentials.
>
> **Note:** In addition to reading the instructions on this page, be sure to read Best practices for [securely using API keys.](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037)
>
> The API supports several types of API keys, including server keys, browser keys, iOS keys, and Android keys.
>
> **Browser keys**
>
> Create and use a Browser key if your application runs on a client, such as a web browser. To prevent your key from being used on unauthorized sites, only allow referrals from domains you administer.

Comment: Please update your question with the information about what you tried that didn't work (and probably your current configuration of the referrers for http://pan-american.ch)